# 1 duplicate symbol for architecture arm64 - Xcode - running out of ideas

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, error-handling

I've had this issue for a few days now, I've tried all the stuff on Stackoverflow so far and have no where to turn to and I don't know what to do.

Error:

> ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture arm64

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any suggestions?

Paste bin to entire log:
https://pastebin.pl/view/dfc1fdca

Relevant entries from the log:

```
Showing Recent Messages
Ld /Users/bradleycable/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Countdown_Widget-hhxapyypudwfqifpmwtzlpoaerys/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Countdown\ Widget.app/Countdown\ Widget normal (in target 'Countdown Widget' from project 'Countdown Widget')
    cd /Users/bradleycable/Desktop/Stuff/Countdown\ Widget
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target arm64-apple-ios14.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.2.sdk -L/Users/bradleycable/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Countdown_Widget-hhxapyypudwfqifpmwtzlpoaerys/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/bradleycable/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Countdown_Widget-hhxapyypudwfqifpmwtzlpoaerys/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/bradleycable/Desktop/Stuff/Countdown\ Widget -filelist /Users/bradleycable/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Countdown_Widget-hhxapyypudwfqifpmwtzlpoaerys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Countdown\ Widget.build/Debug-iphoneos/Countdown\ Widget.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Countdown\ Widget.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/bradleycable/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Countdown_Widget-hhxapyypudwfqifpmwtzlpoaerys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Countdown\ Widget.build/Debug-iphoneos/Countdown\ Widget.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Countdown\ Widget_lto.o -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -L/usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/bradleycable/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Countdown_Widget-hhxapyypudwfqifpmwtzlpoaerys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Countdown\ Widget.build/Debug-iphoneos/Countdown\ Widget.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Countdown_Widget.swiftmodule -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -Xlinker -no_adhoc_codesign -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/bradleycable/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Countdown_Widget-hhxapyypudwfqifpmwtzlpoaerys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Countdown\ Widget.build/Debug-iphoneos/Countdown\ Widget.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Countdown\ Widget_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/bradleycable/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Countdown_Widget-hhxapyypudwfqifpmwtzlpoaerys/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Countdown\ Widget.app/Countdown\ Widget -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/bradleycable/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Countdown_Widget-hhxapyypudwfqifpmwtzlpoaerys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SQLite.swift.build/Debug-iphoneos/SQLite.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SQLite.swiftmodule

duplicate symbol '_main' in:
    /Users/bradleycable/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Countdown_Widget-hhxapyypudwfqifpmwtzlpoaerys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Countdown Widget.build/Debug-iphoneos/Countdown Widget.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Wtarget-fb79391fc42d00bcc0af801429653506c80531174bbc6c7603c27c78464dee8a.o
    /Users/bradleycable/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Countdown_Widget-hhxapyypudwfqifpmwtzlpoaerys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Countdown Widget.build/Debug-iphoneos/Countdown Widget.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Countdown_WidgetApp.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical error that appears during link time due to multiple files exporting the same symbols.

For this particular problem, you seem to have two files in your project that declare the `main` function:

- `Countdown_WidgetApp`,
- and the oddly named `Wtarget-fb79391fc42d00bcc0af801429653506c80531174bbc6c7603c27c78464dee8a`

Take a look at the contents of those files and either remove one from the project or remove the `main` declaration from one of them.